# Is class being called from another class

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class siteMS
 {
    ...
    function __CONSTRUCT()
     {
        require 'config.php';
        $this->config = new siteMSConfig;
        ...
     }
    ...
 }
```

From inside the siteMSConfig class can I determine weather or not it is being called from inside the siteMS class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there's no "pretty" way to do it - you'll end up looking through a [backtrace](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) or something similar.

It would be better to pass an (optional?) parameter to the `siteMSConfig` constructor like this:

```
class siteMSConfig
{
    public function __construct($inSiteMS = false)
    {
    }
}
```

or alternatively, subclass `siteMSConfig`:

```
class siteMSsiteMSConfig extends siteMSConfig
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Possibly call parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is reflection on the call stack possible in PHP?

Comment: Yes, but it's not very pretty - link is in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, you could use [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) to figure out who your caller was.

Writing a class which alters its behaviour based purely on where it called from is asking for a world of pain later on though. Why not parameterise the different behaviour, or make a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to pass it with variable, from what place you called it

```
$this->config = new siteMSConfig ('siteMS');
```